# Calling functions using pandas from an external file

Tags: python, pandas, import

I stored various functions in a file `helpers.py` that I import after `pandas` and `numpy`. To make sure, I import `helpers.py` file last (meaning, after calling `import pandas as pd`, `import numpy as np` etc.)

`helpers.py` contains functions that include pandas objects (mainly DataFrames) and methods.

When I call a function from helpers in my notebook (I use jupyter lab), e.g `helpers.read_FIL(...)`, I receive an error message

```
 "name 'pd' is not defined"
```

I then duplicated the import statements into the helpers.py file.
I keep receiving the same error message.

I don't really understand what's going on, and why 'pd' is still not defined after calling it twice. Is it possible to store functions that use pandas in a separate file at all or should they remain in the main program?

Code sample:

Main notebook:

```py
import pandas as pd
import helpers

df = helpers.read_FILUC(folder=r"G:\PCN\Data Files 2019\Balances check", file="Full_scope.txt")
```

Content of helpers.py:

```py
def read_FILUC(folder, file):
    " read a SAP extract file in folder and convert it into a clean dataframe"
    df = pd.read_table(os.path.join(folder,file), skiprows=2,encoding='ISO-8859-1', dtype='category')
    df = df.drop('Unnamed: 0', axis=1)
    return df
```

Detail of error message received:

```
NameError                              Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-2-9cddf05f0214> in <module>
----> 1 df = helpers.read_FILUC(folder=r"G:\PCN\Data Files 2019\Balances check", file="Full_scope.txt")

G:\PCN\Program files\helpers.py in read_FILUC(folder, file)
      2 def read_FILUC(folder, file):
      3     " read a SAP extract file in folder and convert it into a clean dataframe"
----> 4     df = pd.read_table(os.path.join(folder,file), skiprows=2,encoding='ISO-8859-1', dtype='category')
      5     df = df.drop('Unnamed: 0', axis=1)
      6     return df

NameError: name 'pd' is not defined
```

Comment: Please provide a (minimal-reproducible-example)[https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example]

Comment: If you put `import pandas as pd` as the first line of `helpers.py`, it should work.

Answer (score 0):

Jupyter does not re-load the modules each time the cell is executed.

The import statements shall be included in the external .py file, saved, and, then, the Jupyter kernel needs to be restarted.
Then, it takes the modification of the external file into consideration and get rid of the error mentioned above.